# Azure Batch Job How to split large file into smaller files

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-batch

Want to use Azure Batch Job to process large files, but cannot figure out how and where will i split my large file into smaller file and how do i pass that into Task so that same file is not passed to any other instance of Task

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [JobManager task](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/batch-api-basics/#job-manager-task) to accomplish this. The JobManager task can split the large file, upload the smaller files back to Azure Storage and have the JobManager task kick off tasks that process these smaller files.

Comment: Updated link for [JobManager task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/batchservice/job/add#jobmanagertask)