# Is that possible to split a lager file more than 8 GB using snowflake?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a file more than 8 GB. want to load this file to snowflake. I was going through the snowflake documentation and found the best practices which says keep file size 10 MB to 100 MB for best load performance.

https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/user-guide/data-load-considerations-prepare.html

Is that possible to split the file in snowflake itself? So I will upload 8 GB file to Azure Blob and then will use snowflake to split the file into multiple and then load into a table..?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/68718176/132438 to split files easily into smaller ones.

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not possible to split a file using Snowflake before loading the file.
Snowflake only has the ability to split into multiple files when unloading a table to cloud storage.

But I guess there are possibilities within Azure:
[Azure Batch Job How to split large file into smaller files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37142231/azure-batch-job-how-to-split-large-file-into-smaller-files)

Answer (score 0):

I would add although it's not currently possible today in Snowflake, you are more than welcome to submit a feature request here: https://community.snowflake.com/s/ideas

Comment: Thanks. Submitted the idea here: https://community.snowflake.com/s/ideas